# Internet Explorer extension (Browser Helper Objects) DLL registration error

Tags: internet-explorer, dll, bho, dllregistration

I created a DLL file using Visual Studio 2008 with help of this document:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489(v=vs.85).aspx.
Then I registered the DLL using the command prompt:

`regsvr32 helpnature.dll`

Which gave the following error:

> Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files
>
> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Why is this error given and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note.
When you build the dll, it registers automatically on your machine.So no need to register it again.

If you are trying to register this dll on a separate machine, you need to know if you have all the dependencies existing on that machine. For this you might need to use "Depends.exe" tool for dependency checking.

One fresh machine, you may require to download  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29

Any further information in this regard might help me suggesting better answer.
Rgrds

Answer (score 0):

i also got the same error but it solved try this

regsvr32 (complete path to helpnature.dll) ---for registering BHO

regsvr32 /u (complete path to helpnature.dll) ---for deregistering BHO

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is necessary to check two things:

- The "Platform Target" set in Visual Studio project settings under the "Build" option (Any CPU, x86 or x64) should match the machine where you are trying to register the dll.
- The Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package should be installed in the target machine

Regards,

Johann